Why does my function run twice after calling it on page rendering with useEffect?
When I render the page my function handleInitialSearch should run once, but it runs twice. I assume this is because react renders the page twice, but this will break my gitlab pipeline.
Therefore I am trying to prevent it from running again, but it has to run again on a re-render, therefore I cant just run it at the beginning of the session.
"use client"; import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

//bunch of variables

export default function Home() {
useEffect(() => {
    handleInitiateSearch();
  }, []);
}

async function handleInitiateSearch() {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const roadsResponse = await fetch(`/api?road=all`);
      const roadsData = await roadsResponse.json();
      console.log("Fetch response:", roadsData);
      setRoads(roadsData.roads);
      if (roadsResponse.status == 201) {
        setError(true);
        setErrorMessage(roadsResponse.statusText);
      }
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }

I tried to disable double rendering by react, but that doesn't work.

did you run on dev enviroment with StrictMode? if yes then you can check this answer

"I tried to disable double rendering by react" - how exactly did you attempt that?

Duplicated: React Hooks: useEffect() is called twice even if an empty array is used as an argument
Remove <React.StrictMode> from index.js.
This code will be from this
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

to this
root.render(
    <App />
);

React StrictMode renders components twice on dev server

If you think this is an actual duplicate, you should close-vote and not repost
